# Downloading FEniCS Binary for Linux Mint, what is the difference between the two icons in the following download link?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, linux-mint

I am a new to Linux/Ubuntu operating systems. In this [link](http://fenicsproject.org/download/), I'm not sure which of the first two OS Icons I will need to use. I'll be using Linux Mint. Which one will I need to use? An explanation of the difference of the two would be nice as well. Thanks ahead.

Edit: I'm going to be using Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu so choose the orange circular Ubuntu icon. It's true that Ubuntu is itself based on Debian, but since Linux Mint 17.1 is based on Ubuntu 14.04 *directly*, choose the Ubuntu icon, not the red spiral-shaped Debian icon.

As you can see at the official [Linux Mint Releases](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120102659/http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php) webpage, all of the Linux Mint releases after the first unstable release are based on the Ubuntu package base.